# c++: cast from "const variable*" to "uint32" loses precision

Tags: c++, c, casting

I have two structures rom and transfer.

```
    typedef struct
    {
    const uint32 data;
    }rom;

    typedef struct
    {
    const rom* const read;
    }transfer;

    extern const transfer num;
```

In another C program I have declared

```
transfer* count;
```

and

```
count = (transfer*)(*((uint32*)((uint32)&num) + 2*seqno));
```

Above code compiles in gcc compiler. 
But when I include extern "C" {}, save the file as .cpp and building with g++ compiler it throws me an error. Since direct type cast is not possible with g++ compiler. the error is

> error: cast from 'const transfer*' to 'uint32{{aka unsigned int}'
>   loses precision [-fpermissive]

How could we typecast for c++ compiler?

Comment: The real question is why do you think it's OK to try stuffing an address of a structure into a `uint32`, adding some value to it, then trying to dereference it as a pointer to a 32-bit unsigned `int` value - and **then** treating the result as a pointer to a structure.  Even *if* a pointer would always fit into a 32-bit unsigned `int` value (and it **doesn't**...), the strict aliasing violations abound.  Along with being an incomprehensible mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's so much wrong in that line.

- Don't use home-brewed integer types. Use `stdint.h`/`cstdint`. That is, `uint32_t` and not `uint32`. This goes for C and C++ both.
- `uint32_t` or its home-brewed equivalent is not guaranteed to be able to hold the value of a pointer. This is likely the source of the compiler message. Instead you should be using `uintptr_t`. Which is found in `stdint.h`/`cstdint`.
  (Perhaps the issue isn't so much C versus C++, as one compiler going 64 bit addresses but not the other, or some such.)
- `*(uint32_t*)&some_struct` is a strict aliasing violation in C and C++ both.
  (As it happens you could go from `uint32_t` to struct type if the struct contains `uint32_t` among its members, but not vice versa.)

  If you have no idea what [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) even means, simply *don't* do wild pointer conversions like this, it is undefined behavior. In particular, don't do this on gcc/g++ because it tends to go nuts if you do. (Formally it has the right to go nuts as per the standard...)

Answer (score 0):

Casting pointer to integer, doing arithmetic on that integer, and casting back to pointer is undefined behavior. This is true even for `intptr_t`. The only way to do pointer arithmetic is directly on the pointer.

This is because the mapping between pointer values and intptr_t values is implementation defined and is not mandated they to be the same.

Comment: I don't think that's true. If you convert an integer back to a pointer, and the pointer happens to be one that points to something, or ends up being `nullptr`, the behaviour is defined. But @Lundin is the expert on this, let's see if they comment.

Comment: The only thing you can rely on is casting to `intptr_t` and then casting back to pointer, without doing any arithmetic on the `intptr_r`.